# Oracle SQL - Compare key and values in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

(reverting edit)
I have a table that houses keys and values of configuration for different customer.

```
CustomerID    Key              Value
C1            AskPhoneNo       TRUE
C1            Website          C1Website.com
C1            Report           TRUE 
C2            AskPhoneNo       TRUE
C2            Report           FALSE
C2            AskAddress       TRUE
```

I need to compare the data between C1 and C2 and Show diffs like this

```
C1            AskPhoneNo       TRUE                C2    AskPhoneNo       TRUE
C1            Website          C1Website.com       C2      -               -
C1            Report           TRUE                C2    Report          False
C1            AskAddress       -                   C2    AskAddress
```

What query can be used to get this result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL compare records within a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725341/oracle-sql-compare-records-within-a-table)

Comment: Thanks so much for formatting. I panicked after I clicked the post button.

Comment: @nofinator looking into your suggestion but the expected output  is in a different format. Thank you for linking it though.

Comment: The output format you are requesting doesn't make a lot of sense. There's no point in the two constant columns (one with the value C1, the other C2). There is no reason to repeat the "key" column. The same info can be presented more succintcly - I will show how in an Answer.

Comment: Are there just two customers in the table? Or are you only interested in customers C1 and C2 anyway? Or do you want to compare more customers (C1-C2, C1-C3, C2-C3, …)?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  There will be many customers in the table and the comparison is required for all customer ids.

Comment: The original question was to compare two customers, it's clear. The edit made the question more vague, if you have multiple customers are you comparing select pairs? If yes how do you decide which ones to compare? If you are comparing multiples the output you are asking is not going to work. Can you give us the bigger picture, what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @mdem7.....You are right! Fundamentally the output I'm asking for is not correct. I'll revert the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your required output. First, there's no point in the constant columns (with values C1 and C2 respectively), and there's no reason to repeat the key names. Second, your output seems to show ALL the rows, not just the "differences". If you need to show ALL the rows (whether the values are the same or different), just remove the `where` clause below.

```
with
  test_data(customer_id, key, value) as (
    select 'C1', 'AskPhoneNo', 'TRUE'          from dual union all
    select 'C1', 'Website'   , 'C1Website.com' from dual union all
    select 'C1', 'Report'    , 'TRUE'          from dual union all
    select 'C2', 'AskPhoneNo', 'TRUE'          from dual union all
    select 'C2', 'Report'    , 'FALSE'         from dual union all
    select 'C2', 'AskAddress', 'TRUE'          from dual union all
    select 'C3', 'AskAddress', 'FALSE'         from dual union all
    select 'C3', 'Report'    , 'TRUE'          from dual union all
    select 'C3', 'Website'   , 'C3web.edu'     from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution!)
select key, c1_value, c2_value
from   test_data
pivot  (max(value) for customer_id in ('C1' as c1_value, 'C2' as c2_value))
where  decode(c1_value, c2_value, 0, 1) = 1  -- If needed
order  by key                                -- If needed
;

KEY        C1_VALUE      C2_VALUE     
---------- ------------- -------------
AskAddress               TRUE         
Report     TRUE          FALSE        
Website    C1Website.com
```

Comment: Just my 2 cents, even though this output better than OPs, it not what OP is asking. There might be a use case for the OPs output, or more often than not people ask questions which is a subset of a bigger picture or a one of part of 12 step problem they are trying to solve

Comment: @mdem7 - what I posted can be adapted very easily to give the OP's output, if that is really needed.

Comment: @mathguy Thank you. This format will work. mdem7- Thanks to you too. This is a part of a larger problem I'm trying to solve.  I'm still trying to understand the solution presented since I have never used pivot and decode functions before.

Comment: @mathguy thanks. This solved my problem. I don't quite understand the use of max function though.

Comment: @Silver.Rainbow - `PIVOT` is an aggregate function. Here you have just one `C1` value and one `C2` value for every key; in the more general case, if you had several `C1` or `C2` values for a given key, and you wanted to return just one value in the output, you would need some sort of aggregation. `min` or `max` is often used when you pivot just for display purposes (to turn rows into columns) without really needing an aggregation.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy! I was just reading documentation on pivot. You've taught me something new.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `full outer join + nvl`

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ("CustomerID" varchar2(2), "Key" varchar2(10), "Value" varchar2(13));


INSERT ALL 
    INTO T ("CustomerID", "Key", "Value")
         VALUES ('C1', 'AskPhoneNo', 'TRUE')
    INTO T ("CustomerID", "Key", "Value")
         VALUES ('C1', 'Website', 'C1Website.com')
    INTO T ("CustomerID", "Key", "Value")
         VALUES ('C1', 'Report', 'TRUE')
    INTO T ("CustomerID", "Key", "Value")
         VALUES ('C2', 'AskPhoneNo', 'TRUE')
    INTO T ("CustomerID", "Key", "Value")
         VALUES ('C2', 'Report', 'FALSE')
    INTO T ("CustomerID", "Key", "Value")
         VALUES ('C2', 'AskAddress', 'TRUE')
SELECT * FROM dual;



select 
    nvl(T1."CustomerID",'C1') as CustomerID,
    nvl(T1."Key",T2."Key") as Key,
    T1."Value" as Value,
    nvl(T2."CustomerID",'C2') as CustomerID,
    nvl(T2."Key",T1."Key") as Key,
    nvl(T1."Key",null) as Value
 from (
     select  * from T where "CustomerID" = 'C1'
 ) T1
 full outer join (
     select  * from T where "CustomerID" = 'C2'
 ) T2
 on T1."Key" = T2."Key"
```

> ```
> CUSTOMERID | KEY        | VALUE         | CUSTOMERID | KEY        | VALUE     
> :--------- | :--------- | :------------ | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
> C1         | AskPhoneNo | TRUE          | C2         | AskPhoneNo | AskPhoneNo
> C1         | Report     | TRUE          | C2         | Report     | Report    
> C1         | AskAddress | null          | C2         | AskAddress | null      
> C1         | Website    | C1Website.com | C2         | Website    | Website
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=604a531c149eaca26f8c0e578c8d87ec)*

Comment: I guess `nvl(T1."Key",null) as Value` should be `T2."Value" as Value`?

Comment: The values shown for C2 both in your answer and the in the fiddle aren't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with parameterized Customer IDs

```
with 
 Cust1 as (select 'C1' as C_id from DUAL)
,Cust2 as (select 'C2' as C_id from DUAL)
select (select C_id from Cust1) ID1,
       coalesce(t1.K, t2.K) Key1,
       t1.V as Value1,
       (select C_id from Cust2) ID2,
       coalesce(t2.K, t1.K) Key2,
       t2.V as Value2
 from 
 (select * from t where id = (select C_id from Cust1)) t1
   full outer join (select * from t where id = (select C_id from Cust2)) t2 
   on t1.k = t2.k
```

to test I used

```
with 
 Cust1 as (select 'C1' as C_id from DUAL)
,Cust2 as (select 'C2' as C_id from DUAL)
,t as (
select 'C1' ID, 'AskPhoneNo' K, 'TRUE' V union
select 'C1', 'Website', 'C1Website.com' union
select 'C1', 'Report',  'TRUE' union
select 'C2', 'AskPhoneNo', 'TRUE' union
select 'C2', 'Report', 'FALSE' union
select 'C2', 'AskAddress', 'TRUE')
select (select C_id from Cust1) ID1,
       coalesce(t1.K, t2.K) Key1,
       t1.V as Value1,
       (select C_id from Cust2) ID2,
       coalesce(t2.K, t1.K) Key2,
       t2.V as Value2
 from 
 (select * from t where id = (select C_id from Cust1)) t1
   full outer join (select * from t where id = (select C_id from Cust2)) t2 
   on t1.k = t2.k
```

Comment: I have to try this technique

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to compare data only between 2 customers?

```
Select 
    cust1, key1, val1,
    cust2, key2, val2      
from
    (select CustomerID cust1, key key1, value val1
     from myTable
     where CustomerID = 1) c1 inner join 
    (select CustomerID cust2, key key2, value val2
     from myTable
     where CustomerID = 2) c2 on 
        c1.key1 = c2.key2;
```

I hope, this is self-explanatory. But this particular SQL will work only if you have cust1 and cust2 values. If some of them missing, we need use left and right joins, or a `FULL JOIN`

Comment: This will not return OP's required output. It will return duplicate rows with incorrect info

Comment: This is the result I got using my CTE as the source.  c1 key1 val1 c2 key2 val2
c1 AskAddress TRUE c2 AskAddress TRUE
c1 AskPhoneNo TRUE c2 AskPhoneNo TRUE
c1 AskPhoneNo TRUE c2 AskPhoneNo TRUE
c1 AskPhoneNo TRUE c2 AskPhoneNo TRUE
c1 AskPhoneNo TRUE c2 AskPhoneNo TRUE
c1 Report TRUE c2 Report FALSE
c1 Report TRUE c2 Report TRUE
c1 Report FALSE c2 Report FALSE
c1 Report FALSE c2 Report TRUE
c1 Website C1Website.com c2 Website C1Website.com

Comment: @mdem7 sorry, my bad. will modify now

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare all customers with each other, first join customer to customer. Cross join all keys. Then outer join the data:

```
with customers as (select distinct customerid from mytable)
select
  k.key,
  c1.customerid as customerid1, m1.value as value1,
  c2.customerid as customerid2, m2.value as value2
from customers c1
join customers c2 on c2.customerid > c1.customerid
cross join (select distinct key from mytable) k
left join mytable m1 on m1.customerid = c1.customerid and m1.key = k.key
left join mytable m2 on m2.customerid = c2.customerid and m2.key = k.key
order by customerid1, customerid2, k.key;
```

(I suppose you have a customers table, so you can remove the `WITH` clause.)